# AngularJs rotuer not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I have a small AngularJS application that use the route feature to render ng-view section. For some reason, the controller and view are not rendering as expected.

This is my application:

```
angular.module('sitesApp', ['ngRoute']);
var app = angular.module('sitesApp');

app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider)
{
    $routeProvider.when('/members/sites', {
        templateUrl: '/members/_sites',
        controller: 'SitesCtrl'
    });
}]);

var controllers = {};
controllers.SitesCtrl = function ($scope)
{
    alert('SitesCtrl loaded');
}

app.controller(controllers);
```

My application entry point is "/members/sites". When the user enter this URL, I want that the router will present the file "/members/_sites" in my `ng-view`.

This is how "/members/sites" looks like:

```
<div class="container" ng-app="sitesApp">
    <ng-view></ng-view>
</div>

<script src="~/Scripts/app/Members/sites-app.js"></script>
```

This is how "/members/_sites" looks like:

```
<h1>Hello world!</h1>
```

Expected: SitesCtrl will be loaded and "Hello world" title will be presented on the screen.

Actual: Nothing. SitesCtrl controller wasn't loaded (no alert executed) and nothing on the screen.

I using angularjs 1.4.9 (with angular-route.min.js).

What the problem of this code?

Comment: 1. that's not how you define a controller. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module#controller, 2. you're not using html5 mode, so the router looks what is after the hash in the URL, not what is in the path. Read https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

Comment: This code is based on this http://plnkr.co/edit/sN9TagVBOdX3mkrxaTiu?p=preview